problems with django logout Url
I have a problem with logout, which is when I define the logout path in urls.py:
path ('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='accounts/logout.html'), name='logout')

I get HTTP error 405, which says: this page isn't working right now
but when i change the path to:
path ('logout/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/logout.html'), name='logout')

, it displays logout page, even though, technically, the user is still logged in and the profile is displayed while it should be anonymous!
settings.py
LOGIN_URL = '/account/login/'
LOGOUT_URL = '/account/logout'

urls.py
from django.urls import path 
from. import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views 

urlpatterns = [
 path ('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/login.html'), name='login'),
 path('logout/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/logout.html'), name='logout'),


HTTP error 405 means Method Not Allowed – the logout view requires a POST request, and visiting it directly won't work. See the duplicate and the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/releases/4.1/#log-out-via-get

And naturally you shouldn't use a LoginView for logging out, that won't... log out.

By the way, there's also an option, settings.LOGOUT_ON_GET = True, which might help.
